# How to assign items for loop inside a Model object with Django?

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to override values inside a Model? I am getting 'MyModel' object does not support item assignment.

-- model.py

```
class Slider(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   rows = models.SmallIntegerField(max_length=2)
   cat = models.ForeignKey(Products)
   order = models.SmallIntegerField()
   status = models.BooleanField(default=0)
```

--- views.py

```
rows = Slider.objects.all().order_by('order')

for item in rows:
    product = Products.objects.filter(cat=item.cat)[:10]
    item['product'] = product
    print item
```

Exception Value:'Slider' object does not support item assignment

Comment: That error says that you haven't implemented `__getitem__` on the class.  You could do `item.product = product`, but I'm afraid neither of them will change the database in any way...

Comment: Yeah, you want to add a field `product = models.ForeignKey(Products)` to your model.  Then you can do `item.product = product`.

Comment: You say override, but there is no value `product` in your model to override?

Comment: Are you wanting to persist the value of `product` for a `Slider` in the database?  Or just temporarily?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Each 'slider' to have the top ten products for the same category?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist the value of `product` in the database for a particular `Slider`, then add a [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) field to `Slider`:

```
class Slider(models.Model):
    ...
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products)
```

If you want to have stored temporarily, just add a regular attribute to `Slider` to hold it.

```
class Slider(models.Model):
    ...
    product = None
```

In either case, you'd set it like this:

```
rows = Slider.objects.all().order_by('order')
for item in rows:
    item.product = ...
```

If you prefer you can just leave out the attribute declaration entirely, but this will mean if you go to check for item.product, without having first set it, you would get an [`AttributeError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.AttributeError).